# Prolog list - printing lists before and after element

Tags: list, prolog

Firstly, I'm a total Prolog newbie, my apologies for a silly question!

I am required to write a rule that decomposes a list of months and prints months before `may` and after `may`.

So far, I wrote the following:

```
append_lists([], L, L).
append_lists([H|L1], [L2], [H|L3]) :-
   append_lists(L1, L2, L3).
```

This works great, if I manually query the following:

```
| ?- append_lists(Before, [may|After], [jan, feb, july, may, dec, oct, nov]).
  Before = [jan,feb,july],
  After = [dec,oct,nov] ? ;
  no
```

How can I now rewrite my rule so that `[may|After]` is in place of `L1` in the rule and that it can accept any month? I tried the following but it did not work:

```
append_lists([], L, L).
append_lists([Month|Before], After, [Month|Result]) :-
   append_lists(Before, After, Result).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) to do so.

```
after_and_before(Month, ListOfMonths, Before, After):-
  append(Before, [Month|After], ListOfMonths).
```

Test case:

```
?- after_and_before(may, [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec], Before, After).
Before = [jan, feb, mar, apr],
After = [jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec]
```

Comment: Thank you gusbro! That's very helpful :)